# HTML(Offline) Query Data table and provide links

Tags: html, datatables

Hi I am about to start a new project of mine; create an offline HTML page that will provide a table that can be queried using keywords using multiple terms and based on the result will provide the user the ability use hyperlinks to receive further information.

I started a "database" using excel in the past which did not prove helpful.
So i was hoping to get some advice on where to create the database so that it can be queried through the HTML page.

Cheers
Manny

Comment: You can use text based source (array of arrays) or JSON. example -> https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/36587/using-array-of-objects-json-as-a-data-source export the Excel to CSV and then convert the CSV to JSON.

Comment: Thank for your reply. i was thinking of a database so that the user can user can update the database as well. I assume that i will have to code it so that every time a query is made; the data will be exported into JSON before being queried?

Comment: This is even better.  Just setup a WAMP / LAMP environment and import the CSV to a table. It does have to be connected to the internet, the computer is the server itself and there is a lot of backend scripts designed for DataTables that let you retrieve and update rows.